# How to boost query depends of attribute's value in ElasticSearch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I have a `Profile` class. In ES index I have `company_type` attribute.

```
class Profile
  ...
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  def to_indexed_json
    { name: self.name,
      company_type: self.company.company_type
    }.to_json
  end
end

Tire.search('profiles') do
  query do
    custom_filters_score do
      query { all }

      filter do
        filter :range, last_contact_at: { gte: 7.days.ago }
        boost 1
      end

      score_mode :total
    end
  end
end.results
```

I would like to boost by `10` queries if `company_type == 'intern'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try adding

```
filter do
  filter :term, company_type: "intern"
  boost 10.0
end
```

to your `custom_filters_score` filter?